# How to parse single object from json

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am working on an Android project where I am using volley to parse the data from JSON. I am able to parse the data if it is an array by following [this](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrieve-data-from-mysql-database-in-android-using-volley/) tutorial. But when I try to parse a single object using `getJSONObject`, it is returning `null`. I want to get the value of that particular object.

This is my JSON file:

[image]

In the above file I want to retrieve only `responseInfo` which is a JSON object.

Comment: Add the code you're trying to run

Comment: Log the `jsonObject` from the Logcat to make sure the web server is supplying the right response.

Comment: I suggest you to follow this url for single object.

https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-json-parsing-url-example.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create JSONObject

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(responce);
```

//get responce code

```
 String query = object.getString("responceCode");
```

Comment: thank you the obove code worked like charm :). I fixed my probelm

Comment: @DivakarLuffy if this answer solved your problem don't forget to click the tick to indicate that.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Gson library for json parsing
https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: You should add this in comment . Not separately.